# collapsing nested lists in python to accomodate a variable number of lists (possibly with itertools)

Tags: python, function, python-itertools, nested-lists

I am attempting to expand the function below that takes 2 input lists and uses them to populate an output list, such that each input list is a nested function:

```
import numpy as np

## condition lists 
cond_list_a = [1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0]
cond_list_b = [2,2,2,2,4,4,4,4]

## elements to populate output list 
elem_pool = [3,5]

## function that takes 2 condition lists 
def list_builder (cond_list_a, cond_list_b, elem_pool):

    trials = len(cond_list_a)                              ## output length
    output_list = [0]*trials                               ## creating a base list 

    for elem_a in np.unique(cond_list_a):                  ## for each unique element in condition list a 
        for elem_b in np.unique(cond_list_b):              ## for each unique eleement in condition list b 
            pool_idx = 0                                   ## start the index to draw elements from at 0 
            for i in range(trials):                        
                if (cond_list_a[i] == elem_a) and (cond_list_b[i] == elem_b): ## for each combination 
                    output_list[i] = elem_pool[pool_idx]   ## populate output list
                    pool_idx += 1                          ## update pool index
    return output_list

## run function
list_builder(cond_list_a, cond_list_b, elem_pool)
```

this produces the following output_list = [3, 3, 5, 5, 3, 3, 5, 5]

My goal is to build a function that can take in any number of input lists, to populate an output list in the same way. I have been attempting this for some time now using itertools.product, which could create all possible combinations of input elements, but I am struggling to make this work. I'd be grateful for any ideas. Use of itertools is not a requirement.

Here is an example of one one of my (failed) attempts:

```
import itertools as it

## list of condition lists: 
cond_lists = [cond_list_a, cond_list_b]

## function that could take handle any number of condition lists 
def better_list_builder(condition_lists, elem_pool):

    trials = len(condition_lists[0])                            ## output length
    ouput_list = [0]*trials                                     ## creating a base list 
    
    cond_list_combos = list(it.product(*condition_lists))       ## get all the list combos
    uniq_combos = list(set(cond_list_combos))                   ## pare them down to the unique element combinations
    
    for each_combo in uniq_combos:                              ## for each combination of elements
        for j in range(len(condition_lists)):                   ## for each input condition list
            pool_idx = 0                                        ## start the index to draw elements from at 0        
            for i in range(trials):  
                if condition_lists[j][i] == each_combo[j]:      ## if the condition combo matches that list entry
                    output_list[i] = elem_pool[pool_idx]        ## populate output list
                    pool_idx += 1                               ## update pool index
    
    return output_list

## run function                    
better_list_builder(condition_lists, elem_pool)
```

Answer (score 0):

got it!

```
def list_builder (cond_list_master, elem_pool):

    trials = len(cond_list_master[0])                  ## output length
    output_list = [0]*trials                           ## creating a base list 

    somelist = []
    for idx in range(len(cond_list_master)):
        somelist.append(np.unique(cond_list_master[idx]))

    for element in itertools.product(*somelist):  # element is what you called (elem_a, elem_b, elem_c etc. )
        pool_idx = 0                                   ## start the index to draw elements from at 0 
        for i in range(trials): 
            flag = True
            for idx in range(len(cond_list_master)):
                flag = flag and (element[idx] == cond_list_master[idx][i])
            if flag:
                output_list[i] = elem_pool[pool_idx]   ## populate output list
                pool_idx += 1                          ## update pool index
    return output_list
```